# Как визуализировать структуру зависимостей и связей excel-файлов?

Tags: excel, поиск-программ, excel-формулы

Существует информационная система, состоящая из множества excel файлов с множеством листов с множеством данных и формул. Есть ли инструмент, который может визуализировать связи, существующие в этой системе?

Comment: Доска и фломастеры :) А если серьезно - не видел, не слышал, не встречал.

Comment: Я пробовал стандартным аудитом формулы пользоваться, но это не так наглядно и совсем не так масштабно (приходится прокликивать каждую формулу и относительно неё искать влияющие и зависимые ячейки).

Answer (score 0):

Тоже "не видел, не слышал, не встречал". Когда-то сам писал на VBA что-то подобное. У меня был один рабочий лист, на котором были тысячи блоков, между которыми были связи. Нужно было сгруппировать блоки, которые имеют между собой связи, и для каждого блока вывести список ссылок на другие блоки и список ссылок на этот блок. Программа не очень большая и не очень сложная.

Наверняка существуют инструменты, которые могут визуализировать связи между объектами. Можно организовать результаты работы анализатора так, чтобы их можно было импортировать в подобный инструмент.

Comment: Больш смахивает на комментарий,  чем на полноценный  ответ.

Comment: @Mpmp ответ - это необязательно готовая программа или кусок кода. Хорошая идея ценнее этого. Когда я решал свою задачу, никаких современных средств визуализации небыло. Получил таблицу с результатами и пользовался. Яд, по-видимому, собирается модернизировать какое-то приложение. Может, ему и визуализация не потребуется. Скорее всего окажется, что набор данных не так сложен, как видится сейчас.